# Tkinter widget becoming NoneType

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Here's my code, I'm trying to make the border on a frame disappear when another is clicked, and have the clicked frame get a border. I'm storing the currently bordered widget in `self.selectedColor`, but when I try to use that variable in `newDrawColor`, the variable is NoneType. Here's the exact error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 22, in newDrawColor
    self.selectedColor.config(highlightthickness=0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

And here's the code:

```
def initUI(self):

    self.title("Template Maker")

    choice = Frame(self, width=20, height=20, bg="#eeeeee", bd=20, highlightthickness=2,highlightbackground="#000")
    self.selectedColor = choice
    choice.pack(side="left")
    choice.bind("<Button-1>", self.newDrawColor)

    choice = Frame(self, width=20, height=20, bg="#d6e685", bd=20, highlightbackground="#000")
    choice.pack(side="left")
    choice.bind("<Button-1>", self.newDrawColor)

    choice = Frame(self, width=20, height=20, bg="#8cc665", bd=20, highlightbackground="#000")
    choice.pack(side="left")
    choice.bind("<Button-1>", self.newDrawColor)

    choice = Frame(self, width=20, height=20, bg="#44a340", bd=20, highlightbackground="#000")
    choice.pack(side="left")
    choice.bind("<Button-1>", self.newDrawColor)

    choice = Frame(self, width=20, height=20, bg="#1e6823", bd=20, highlightbackground="#000")
    choice.pack(side="left")
    choice.bind("<Button-1>", self.newDrawColor)
    ... End important part of function

def newDrawColor(self, ev):
    ev.widget.config(highlightthickness=2)
    self.selectedColor.config(highlightthickness=0)
    self.selectedColor = ev.widget
    self.drawColor = ev.widget["background"]
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong here? Does something happen when the mainloop is run that wipes variables? What can I do to fix this problem?

EDIT:

Interestingly, using a global variable (bad practice, I know) works. Additionally, after a bit of debugging, it looks like the attribute is set to NoneType after the application class is constructed, but before the mainloop is run. Still would love a non-global solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was much simpler than I was thinking; in the constructor function, after I call init UI, I set self.selectedColor to None. I originally did this to act as a default, before I  moved assignment to initUI, and forgot to delete the line.